# iPhone Dev: triggering Copy function UIResponderStandardEditActions for selection on UIWebView

Tags: iphone, text, uiwebview, copy, selection

Please kindly give me some advice on the following requirement:

1. To select a text from a page loaded on a UIWebView
2. To trigger the Copy function using another button instead of the standard Copy from the UIMenuController

What I would like achieve is basically the storing of the highlighted/selected text into a persistence. And I thought it can be done by having a button to call a function that does both copying and pasting ~ eventually storing into persistence... all at one button-click.

The two points above is the only part I couldn't get in the overall process of storing I need for my simple app.

Comment: Hi oonoo, you got the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Answering an old question I know, but it would seem that this SO question might be your answer: [Perform copy/cut from UIResponderStandardEditActions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8031175/perform-copy-cut-from-uiresponderstandardeditactions) - it guides you to send the action along the responder chain. Just call the code from the IBAction method linked to the relevant control.

If you have since found the answer, please do post it!