# Perform copy/cut from UIResponderStandardEditActions

Tags: iphone, uimenucontroller, uiresponder

These are standart actions for UIMenuController declared http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIResponderStandardEditActions_Protocol/UIResponderStandardEditActions.html

How can I perform these methods manually, like from another UIMenuItem or whatever?
I can't find the right selector:(

1. [self cut:sender];
2. [UIResponder cut:sender];
3. [[UIMenuController sharedMenuController] cut:sender];
4. - (void) cut: (id) sender {[super cut:sender];}

So far non of these don't work, selector not found.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to send the action along the responder chain, starting with the "first responder". Try this:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] sendAction:@selector(cut:) to:nil from:self forEvent:nil];
```

If you have the UIEvent that triggered the action, you might pass that as the last parameter.

You can read about the responder chain in [*Event Handling Guide for iOS*: Event Delivery: The Responder Chain](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/event_delivery_responder_chain/event_delivery_responder_chain.html).