# Handle copy: paste: cut: in UIWebView

Tags: ios, uiwebview

How to hadle copy: paste: cut: events in UIWebView?
As Apple says, we can not subclass UIWebView,
so how can I handle UIResponderStandardEditActions?
Maybe someone faced with such a difficulties...

I need to implement custom copy,cut,paste in order to copy/paste html (RTF text, some custom html elements).
In addition, I have 2 webviews, so if I paste some elements in one, another one should reply for this interaction.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with this? You could handle it differently depending on what you're doing.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I think you are going to have to make your own copy/paste menu.

Using the answer from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8031175/perform-copy-cut-from-uiresponderstandardeditactions) you can set up custom copy/paste buttons, and you could handle everything you are trying to do through those:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] sendAction:@selector(cut:) to:nil from:self forEvent:nil];
```

Also, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1604716/customize-uimenucontroller) shows how to make a custom UIMenuController and use the UILongPressGestureRecognizer to get it to show up on the UIWebView.

I hope this helps. Someone else may know an easier way, but I think this way will work at least.

Comment: @Altaveron No, it doesn't cut anything; it allows you to handle cutting something using your own code. Standard cut/copy/paste is automatically provided in a `UIWebView`.